# QT 5.5.1 removed -universal option: no way of creating universal binaries on MAC

Tags: qt, qt5, osx-yosemite, qmake, qt5.5

Why is `-universal` option removed from `./configure` script?

How do i create universal binary from source?
I am able to create 32-bit and 64-bit frameworks separately as follows:

1) 64-bit QT framework

```
 #Choose platform from qtbase/mkspecs/
./configure  -release -opensource -confirm-license -prefix /tmp/  -nomake tests -nomake examples  -platform macx-clang
 #Only needed QTcore, QTNetwork, QTGui module, so i choose "module-qtbase"
 make -j4 module-qtbase
```

Copy `qtbase/lib/` somewhere before creating 32-bit

2) 32-bit QT framework

```
./configure  -release -opensource -confirm-license -prefix /tmp/  -nomake tests -nomake examples  -platform macx-clang-32
 make -j4 module-qtbase
```

Now its cumbersome to use `lipo` on 32bit `qtbase\lib` and 64bit `qtbase\lib`. Is there any new way of creating universal binaries on MAC?

I still need to support 32bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to write this manually as following.
If anyone else comes up with better answer i'll accept theirs.

```
#This is in qt-everywhere/src/ directory
#Build for 32-bit
./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -prefix ~/tmp/  -nomake tests -nomake examples -openssl-linked -I $(OPENSSL_INC) -L $(OPENSSL_LIB) -platform macx-clang-32
make

#Backup required 32-bit binaries. I only needed qtbase and plugins
#-R because frameworks contain symlinks
cp -Rf qtbase/lib ../out_32/lib
cp -Rf qtbase/plugins ../out_32/plugins

make clean
./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -prefix ~/tmp/  -nomake tests -nomake examples -openssl-linked -I $(OPENSSL_INC) -L $(OPENSSL_LIB) -platform macx-clang
make

#Backup required 64-bit binaries.
cp -Rf qtbase/lib ../out_64/lib
cp -Rf qtbase/plugins ../out_64/plugins

cd ..
#creating universal frameworks
FR="QtGui QtCore QtNetwork QtWidgets"
for fr in ${FR}; do
   rm -rf out/$fr.framework
   cp -Rf out_64/lib/$fr.framework out/
   rm -rf out/$fr.framework/Versions/Current/$fr

   lipo -create -output out/$fr.framework/Versions/Current/$fr \
                        out_32/lib/$fr.framework/Versions/Current/$fr \
                        out_64/lib/$fr.framework/Versions/Current/$fr
done
```

`out` directory contains universal frameworks.